# how to echo back the whole mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

i have this SQL code :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM functions
      WHERE user_name='ben ' 
      AND (function_description LIKE '%xxx%') ";
```

it give me back two lines on phpmyadmin SQL  :

```
user_name   function_type   function_name   function_description
ben         PHP         PHP1            that xxx
ben         PHP         PHP2            lofaif adnan xxx i
```

but when i tried to echo back those lines using this :

```
$results=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['function_name'] . " : " . $row['function_description'] . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

it give me back just this :

```
PHP2:lofaif adnan xxx i
```

and i want to echo back the 2 lines .. whats the problem with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop you are currently in will only print out the current iteration. To print out all rows in the DB simply initialise the `$rows` variable as an array `$rows = array();` and assign all the rows to it via `while($rows[]=mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))`. Your `$rows` variable should now contain all the DB records.

```
$results=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
$row = array();
while($rows[]=mysql_fetch_array($results));

//should not contain all rows
print_r( $rows );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO to return an all-in-one array of your result set using `fetchAll()`:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass)
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage())
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Note that PDO requires additional extension which could not be available. Am I right?

Comment: Hi. I guess, but PDO has been available by default with PHP for a few versions now. I'm making an assumption that it's available. Moreover, it's the recommended database interface to use, since it provides a lot of useful features and additional security like prepared statements etc.